# Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio (2012)

Tags: ssms, sql-server-express

Here is the image that pop ups

[image]

Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio (2012)

I hope someone can help me with SSMS, because I can't create table even though I can connect.
Showing this error message every time I try to create table

> TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
> This backend version is not supported to design database diagrams or tables. (MS Visual Database Tools)

Comment: So, which SQL Server version are you running?

Comment: The error is telling you the problem. Why are you using SSMS 2012 for a 2019 instance? Use a version of SSMS that supports 2019.

Comment: @Filburt you can still use the table designer in SSMS against Express (though that doesn't mean to should, as writing the SQL is far better). It's that the OP is using a version that is 7 years older than the database back end that's the issue; SSMS 2012 doesn't support SQL Server 2019.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is literally telling you the problem here, the version of SSMS you are using (SSMS 2012) does not support the back end version that you are using (SQL Server 2019). *I can tell it's 2019 because in the top left of that image it has Version 15.....*.

The first version of SSMS to provide support for SQL Server 2019 was SSMS [18.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/release-notes-ssms?view=sql-server-ver15#180), which was release on 2019-04-19.

> #### What's new in 18.0
>
> | New item | Details |
> | --- | --- |
> | Support for SQL Server 2019 | SSMS 18.0 is the first release that is fully aware of SQL Server 2019 (compatLevel 150). |
> | Support for SQL Server 2019 | Support for "BATCH_STARTED_GROUP" and "BATCH_COMPLETED_GROUP" in SQL Server 2019 and SQL Managed Instance. |
> | Support for SQL Server 2019 | SMO: Added support for UDF Inlining. |
> | Support for SQL Server 2019 | GraphDB: Add a flag in showplan for Graph TC Sequence. |
> | Support for SQL Server 2019 | Always Encrypted: added support for AEv2 / Enclave. |
> | Support for SQL Server 2019 | Always Encrypted: connection dialog has a new tab "Always Encrypted" when the user clicks on the "Options" button to enable/configure Enclave support. |

You need to update to a version of SSMS that *supports* the back end version you are using. Personally, I would suggest updating to the latest version, which is currently 18.9.1.

Comment: Thankyou so much it worked now, I'm now currently using SSMS 2018.

Comment: SSMS 18, @Howard, *not* 2018.